# Responsive Banner Ads

Tags: html, css, ads, banner

I am adding banner code into a new website and I need them to be responsive.

I have the Top Banner (728x90) ad working but when I try to get the Skyscraper to be responsive it does not work.

This is the CSS code I am using to make the banner responsive:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #Banner img {
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: 95% !important;
    }

    #Banner {
        width: auto !important;
        max-width: 900px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You need to provide way more information here. Responsive design isn't just a cut and dry thing, it's what you want it to be and what your goals are. People can't read your mind. You also need to post the HTML, as CSS without HTML or a clear direction isn't going to get you any help

Comment: ....and try and cut down on the `!important` statements.

Comment: I got it working by specifying `height`. You only get ads in predefined sizes. If you would like a differently sized ad use a media query and specify height and width to match one of these: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2953032

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Google Adsense: their [responsive ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689) are in beta, but as far as I've tested them, they seem to work well. Note: they don't really "scale", but they'll change on different resolutions.

For instance: on a large monitor, I will see a broad ad, and on a smaller one a small ad, but there is no middle-road.

The generated code (by Google) will look like this:

```
<style>
.responsive-sidebar-ad { width: 320px; height: 50px; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .responsive-sidebar-ad { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .responsive-sidebar-ad { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Responsive sidebar ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle responsive-sidebar-ad"
     style="display:inline-block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Now that you have the code, you can change the media queries according to your design.